# "Ipcalc -n ipv6_addr" command is giving error

Tags: networking, scripting, ipv6

I am trying to calculate network address of Ip address by using **Ipcalc** command.

when i am using ipcalc -n ipv4 address,then it is running fine and give the network address for the IPv4.

But when i am using the same command with ipv6 address, then it is giving some errors.

For example

$ipcalc -n 192.168.456.52/16

output -->Network=192.168.0.0         --> this output is fine

but when i am using

$ipcalc -n 2001:0db8:0a0b:12f0:0000:0000:0000:0001/64

output --> ipcalc: Bad IP address

How can i solve this?????.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It works for me. How old is your system?

Comment: Can u please tell me which version of redhat you are using and which version of initscript package you are using??

Comment: You need to be more specific about which `ipcalc` you are talking. The `ipcalc` package in Debian and Ubuntu, e.g., contains [ipcalc by Krischan Jodies](http://jodies.de/ipcalc) which is ten years old and understands only IPv4.

Answer (score 4):

> How can i solve this?????.

You will have to read the documentation<sup>1</sup> for your version of ipcalc for yourself to determine the solution to your problem but my guesses

- your version of ipcalc does not support IPv6
- you need to add the `-6` switch (or similar) to advise the program you are providing an IPv6 address.
- Gravity waves

<sup>1</sup> You didn't provide any info about your version of ipcalc or which Distro/OS  and version you are using so I can't provide RMAAS for you.

Comment: Hello lain, if ipcalc is running on your system . Then can u please answer these two things  :**1** which **version of Redhat** you are using and **2**   which **version of initscripts** you are using??????